# Use of Windows undefined environment variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

Here's a simple but puzzling question.

For an undefined Windows environment variable, abc for example

In the Command Prompt window ECHO [%abc%] results in [%abc%]

But in a .CMD batch file     ECHO [%abc%] results in []

Why the difference? I've researched the ECHO command and can't find anything about this. I'm concerned about where else this subtle difference might apply.

Comment: If you are really interested, work through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/6811411) highlighting the internal parsing of batch and cmd line interpreter.

Comment: A short summarize: It's independent of the `ECHO` command, the expansion rules differs from cmd context with batch file context

Comment: You may make good use of this point in some ways. For example, at the command prompt: `for %a in (*.txt) do @set "var=%a" & call echo File: %var%`. Remember that `var` variable must be undefined in order for this to work...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did not know of the parsing difference. I read LotPings "answer" about this. Way too many differences between CMD Window and .CMD file !

Just a short time ago I posed a question about CALL SET differences, which are now probably explained by the parsing difference.

Bottom Line: I no longer trust testing anything in CMD Window. Want to test something? Test it in a .CMD file.

For example, like copying and pasting code fragments from posts on this site. If you paste them in a CMD Window you may not get the expected results.

Anarchy !

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347593/whats-the-difference-between-bat-and-cmd-file) explains it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: [undefined environmental variable expansion in cmd vs batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39707858/995714)

Comment: it's about variable substitution so obviously you won't find anything if you read echo's help http://stackoverflow.com/q/16367814/995714

Answer (score 1):

Really good question! Confusing huh?

There are actually two distinct parsers used to parse batch scripts and command line commands.

Quote from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1093508):

> `BatchLineParser` - The parser inside of batch files, for lines or blocks
>
> `CmdLineParser` - Like the `BatchLineParser`, but directly at the command prompt, works different

The key difference is in the first phase of parsing, particularly the extension of `%var%`:

In `BatchLineParser` if `var` does not exists will be replaced with nothing, in `CmdLineParser` if the `var` isn't defined, the expression will be unchanged.

So why did someone design it this way? I have absolutely no idea.